# React Native AlertIOS placeholder

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using [AlertIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alertios) with input:
[image]

```
AlertIOS.prompt(
  'Reset password',
  'Please enter your email in order to reset your password.',
  [
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
      style: 'cancel',
    },
    {
      text: 'Continue',
      onPress: (password) => console.log('OK Pressed, password: ' + password),
    },
  ],
  'plain-text',
  '',
  'email-address'
);
```

I wish to add a placeholder for the TextInput inside that alert. Is this possible? I know there is a default value option, however I wish to have a placeholder instead of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically it is possible in iOS, is it possible in react-native? The short answer is currently no.

The reason it is not possible is that the placeholder property of the TextField hasn’t been exposed to the react-native side.  If we look st the code in `RCTAlertManager.m` we can see that defaults for the `placeholder` are set for the `Password` and `Login` options, but there is no way to set them of the `plain-text` option

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Modules/RCTAlertManager.m

```
switch (type) {
    case RCTAlertViewStylePlainTextInput: {
      [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.secureTextEntry = NO;
        textField.text = defaultValue;
        textField.keyboardType = keyboardType;
      }];
      break;
    }
    case RCTAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput: {
      [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = RCTUIKitLocalizedString(@"Password");
        textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
        textField.text = defaultValue;
        textField.keyboardType = keyboardType;
      }];
      break;
    }
    case RCTAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput: {
      [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = RCTUIKitLocalizedString(@"Login");
        textField.text = defaultValue;
        textField.keyboardType = keyboardType;
      }];
      [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = RCTUIKitLocalizedString(@"Password");
        textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
      }];
      break;
    }
    case RCTAlertViewStyleDefault:
      break;
  }
```

The only way to make this work is to find a dependency that has the ability to set the `placeholder` for the `TextInput` in the `Alert`. Or you could make your own native module based on the code in `RCTAlertManager.m` that allows you to set the `placeholder`